# Connect Sphinx autodoc-skip-member to my function

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I want to use [sphinx's autodoc-skip-member](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-skip-member) event to select a portion of the members on a certain python class for documentation.

But it isn't clear from the sphinx docs, and I can't find any examples that illustrate: where do I put the code to connect this? I see [Sphinx.connect](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.connect) and I suspect it goes in my conf.py, but when I try variations on this code in conf.py I can't find the app object that I should connect():

```
def maybe_skip_member(app, what, name, obj, skip,
                                  options):
    print app, what, name, obj, skip, options
    return False

# This is not even close to correct:
#from sphinx.application import Sphinx
#Sphinx().connect('autodoc-skip-member', maybe_skip_member)
```

A pointer to a simple example would be ideal.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Aha, last ditch effort on a little googling turned up [this example](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/attachment/ticket/7813/conf.py), scroll down to the bottom. Apparently a setup() function in conf.py will get called with the app. I was able to define the following at the bottom of my conf.py:

```
def maybe_skip_member(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    print app, what, name, obj, skip, options
    return True

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', maybe_skip_member)
```

Which is obviously useless (it skips everything), but that's the minimal example I was looking for and couldn't find...

Answer (score 16):

This answer expands upon the [answer by bstpierre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3757526/832230). It implements [`autodoc-skip-member`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-skip-member). Below is the relevant portion from my `conf.py`:

```
autodoc_default_flags = ['members', 'private-members', 'special-members',
                         #'undoc-members',
                         'show-inheritance']

def autodoc_skip_member(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21449475/
    exclusions = ('__weakref__',  # special-members
                  '__doc__', '__module__', '__dict__',  # undoc-members
                  )
    exclude = name in exclusions
    # return True if (skip or exclude) else None  # Can interfere with subsequent skip functions.
    return True if exclude else None
 
def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', autodoc_skip_member)
```

Comment: For me, this has no effect, all the new rst files are created by `sphinx-autodoc` as they were before.  Is this approach supposed to work now?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone comes searching for same question but for **AutoAPI** instead of autodoc, the below snippet successfully excludes all attributes and methods from the AutoAPI generated documentation that begin with `_`; this isn't a great idea in practice but I wanted to start with something drastic for ease of detection.

```py
def autoapi_skip_member(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    """Exclude all private attributes, methods, and dunder methods from Sphinx."""
    import re
    exclude = re.findall('\._.*', str(obj))
    return skip or exclude


def setup(app):
    """Add autoapi-skip-member."""
    app.connect('autoapi-skip-member', autoapi_skip_member)
```

One quirk/oddity to call out is that that the same functions applied to `name` instead of `str(obj)` in the `autoapi_skip_member` function doesn't seem to work, which I was (apparently) mistakenly under the impression were the same thing ('[fully qualified name of the object](https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/config.html)' per the AutoAPI docs).

This includes when throwing in something like the below to detect methods that start with `_`:

```py
or (hasattr(obj, '__name__') and str(obj.__name__).startswith('_'))
```

Comment: this works  better for me https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/config.html?highlight=skip#event-autoapi-skip-member