# Get "flat" member output for sphinx automodule

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using the Sphinx autodoc extension to document a module, and I'd like to get a *flat* list of the module's members in the documentation output.

I tried using the following:

```
.. automodule:: modname
   :members:
```

However, there are two problems with this:

1. It includes the module's docstring, which I *don't* want here.
2. The name of each entry is prefixed with "modname.", which is completely redundant (since this page is specifically for documenting this module)

However, I haven't been able to find any config options that would let me selectively disable these two aspects while still getting the automatic listing of all of the module members.

My current plan is to just use autofunction (etc) and explicitly enumerate the members to be documented, but I'd still like to know if I missed an easy way to achieve what I originally wanted.

**Update:** I at least found a workaround for the second part: set `add_module_names=False` in `conf.py`. That's a global setting though, so it doesn't really answer my original question.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, not a comment, so it can be voted on.

Comment: Updated to make it clearer that I never actually answered my original question - I just found a partial workaround for one part of it. I now suspect that there simply isn't an easy way to do what I originally wanted. (And my desire for it has faded, as I've improved the structure of the relevant part of the documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3757526/183066) to a similar question, I've found that you can use the [`autodoc-process-docstring`](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) event to remove the docstrings from modules appending the following code to your `conf.py`:

```
def skip_modules_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    if what == 'module':
        del lines[:]

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', skip_modules_docstring)
```

Note that the `del` statement is needed because, according to the documentation, the modification to `lines` must happend in place (it you create a new object, it doesn't work).

Finally, you can also use `name` to filter the docstrings of just a few modules while keeping the ones from others.