# Ignore some modules in autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, autodoc

I'm trying to use autodoc for selected modules only. I've created a file which includes:

```
.. automodule:: some.specific.module
   :members:
```

And it gets generated correctly. Unfortunately autodoc keeps trying to parse other files too (and fails because of import errors). I know I can mock out some modules, but I want a better solution - stop sphinx from looking at them to begin with.

How can I make sure only the requested module is loaded, and not (for example) `test.other.module`.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/21449475/344286 do what you want? If so I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turned out to be a stupid mistake. Since some tools generate a scaffold for api documentation sources, those files were left laying around and triggered bad imports.

How this was found:

- sphinx has multiple levels of debug logging which do not normally get activated
- you can see which lines trigger imports by debug output like

```
 [autodoc] /path/to/the/doc.rst:158: input:
 .. automodule:: app.module.name
    :members:
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing three possible causes for this to happen:

- Sphinx's cache is causing trouble, and `make clean` would solve the issue
- Your module is located in a package, and the package's `__init__.py` file
  is importing these "other files" (or to be more accurate is trying to 
  import them);
- These "other files" are imported because you have set [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP)