# Skip Empty Modules - Sphinx Autodoc

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using Sphinx to build documentation for a package. I can't find a way to skip (remove) empty submodules when building doc. Example in `Section 2` there is a subsection named `Submodule` which is blank I want to skip such subsections. I tried using the following code.

```
def skip_util_classes(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    if what == "Submodules":
        skip = True
    return skip


def setup(sphinx):
    sphinx.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip_util_classes)
```

The above code is not eliminating section `Submodules`.

I want to know how can I define a section or subsection that needs to be skipped? And how can I define empty section or subsection that I want to skip in `skip_util_classes`?

Comment: `autodoc-skip-member` cannot be used to remove sections from .rst files. Why do you have empty sections in the first place?

Comment: When I use `sphinx-apidoc -f -o <path-to-output> <path-to-module>` to create .rst file it creates headings as `Subpackages` which is empty and I want to avoid such empty headings when creating .rst files

Comment: Two ideas: 1) Create a custom sphinx-apidoc template. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57520238/407651. 2) Don't run sphinx-apidoc over and over again. Run the tool once, fix the output and add it to source control. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481785/407651.

Comment: That was helpful. Could you tell when to use `skip_util_classes`? Why is it not applicable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the `skip_util_classes` function (a handler for the `autodoc-skip-member` event) is used when you want Sphinx to ignore certain members of Python modules or classes. See [Connect Sphinx autodoc-skip-member to my function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3757500/407651).

This technique cannot be used to skip or remove sections in generated .rst files. Here are two suggestions that might help with that problem:

1. Create a custom sphinx-apidoc template. See [Remove the word "module" from Sphinx documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50361218/407651).
2. Don't run sphinx-apidoc over and over again. Run the tool once, tweak the output and add it to source control. See [Keeping the API updated in Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28481471/407651).